# How to convert a list of dictionaries to CSV format in Python, assuming the dictionaries can have different keys?

Tags: python, sql, csv, dictionary, key

I have a list of dictionaries like that :

```
[
{'item1':'bla', 'item2':'bli', 'item3':'blu'},
{'item1':'love', 'item3':'python'}
]
```

Notice that dict 2 doesn't have key 'item2'.
I want to produce a csv output as such, so I can insert everything into a SQL table:

```
item1,item2,item3
bla,bli,blu
love,,python
```

I found an easy way to do that if all dictionaries share the same keys, but I don't see how to do that elegantly if that is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`csv.DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) with the `fieldnames` and `restval` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
#Create a master list of keys
allKeys = ()
for row in YourListHere:
    allKeys.union(row.keys())

#Sort the keys
allKeys = list(allKeys).sorted()

#Go through printing the rows
for row in YourListHere:
    values = []
    for key in allKeys:
        #Add the values if it exists, if no key in this row add a blank
        if key in row:
            values.append(row[key])
        else:
            values.append('')
    print ','.join(values)
```

Comment: Why would you do this yourself when `csv.DictWriter` does it for you?  See my answer.

Comment: Probably just because I put up example code.  Your answer requires looking up the syntax.  I haven't used the csv library, it looks like it's probably a good solution though.

Comment: I also wanted to take a look at the data rather than directly writing a file. But in the future I am sure I will be using your solution, when I'm more confident about what I do.

Comment: Suit yourself, but keep in mind that in Python world, 15 minutes of reading the standard library docs and trying it out is often worth and hour of coding and many hours of maintenance.